# ip a doesn't show network interface

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have two versions of Linux installed on my system, the first a Pop! OS installation with working Wifi and the second a Debian installation with non-working Wifi. When using `ip a` in Pop! OS I see the wireless device along with the wifi kernel (`iwlwifi`). When using the same command in Debian, I only see the auto lo interface and eth0. In Debian I can see the wireless interface using `lspci`.

Before reaching this stage I tried some configuration stuff using `wpasupplicant` but I can't remember the source. I modified a settings file somewhere that wasn't `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Any recommendations?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Needed to install firmware-iwlwifi.